# Determining data cost for webpages

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find out the data cost of a webpage. I think one way of doing it is to go to Inspect Element -> Network for a webpage and then take the sum of the "Size" column to get the total data cost as shown in the screenshot.

Is there a way to do this using JavaScript so I don't have to do it manually by clicking inspect element etc.?
So e.g. a program where I would type bbc.com which outputs "500KB" as the total amount of data on the page.

(I am new to JS if it's not blindingly obvious)

Comment: Well if you want to measure the size of the body data from the initial request, you could just do a GET and check the content length header. However the site will most likely rely on other assets that will require additional requests, some of which could even be triggered by scripts. To account for that, you would need to render out the webpage with an actual engine of some sort (such as a headless browser) and measure the total data accumulated from each request over a given period of time. Still wouldn't be exactly accurate however, as the site can request more data at any time.

Comment: How would I get the content length header? I have been trying the requests library in python and sending a GET request but the "content-length" header doesn't always seem to exist.

Comment: If that's not possible, you could just buffer the body and measure it.